# Read status of server members and give/remove roles , discord.js v14

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I need my bot read member servers status and if here write my server tag ( discord.gg/... ) give them role and if they take it out remove it. How can i do this?

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get('910192386267840513');
const member = newPresence.member;
const activities = member.user.presence.activities[0];

if (activities && (activities.state.includes('.gg/') || activities.state.includes('discord.gg/'))) {
    return newPresence.member.roles.add(role);
}
else if (member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
    newPresence.member.roles.remove(role);
}});
```

I found that code but giving errors.

EDIT 2

I changed my code and didn't give errors but doesn't working.

```
 const {Client, ActivityType,GatewayIntentBits,Partials,} = require("discord.js");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.User,
    Partials.GuildMember,
    Partials.Reaction,
  ],
});

module.exports = client;



client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    if (newPresence.activities.some(a => a.state && a.state.includes("gg"))) {
        console.log(" 1 role gave");
        newPresence.member.roles.add("1127983091386962060");
    } else {
        newPresence.member.roles.remove("1127983091386962060");
    }
});
```

Comment: What errors? You should add it to your question. And why `member.user.presence`? Users don't have `presence`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Sorry i'm new here i will edit.

`member.user.presence`  i found that code by another site.

Comment: No worries, but `member.user.presence` should be `member.presence`. And you need to have the correct intents enabled.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I changed and add correct intents but doesn't working. Can you check my code?

Comment: You need to add the `GuildMembers` intent too to work with roles.

Comment: I add GuildMembers but bot not giving roles. @ZsoltMeszaros

Comment: Does your bot have the manage roles permission? Is your bot's role above the roles you want the bot to assign to members? You should check the errors and see what's wrong. Also, use try-catch or `catch` with those promises (`roles.add()` and `roles.remove()`) .

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I put that code `console.log(newPresence.activities);` for test but i didn't see anything on console.  Bot can't read status.

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo, or can you post your full code on pastebin.com and  send the link for us?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I fugired something , my event file not even working i tried send message to consol bUt nothing happend. What can i do?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Thank you so much. I deleted Intents and write `const client = require("mainfilename"); ` its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code has a lot of repetitions and unnecessary lines!
Here is a shortened version of it:

```js
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    if (newPresence.activities.some(a => a.state && a.state.includes("discord.gg")) {
        newPresence.member.roles.add("role_id");
    } else {
        newPresence.member.roles.remove("role_id");
    }
});
```

You can always modify the code as per your use.

I recommend using the following intents for the code to work:

- `Guilds`
- `GuildMembers`
- `GuildPresences`

Make sure to enable privileged intents on your [developer portal](https://discord.dev/) too!

Reference: [Presence](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Presence), [GuildMemberRoleManager](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMemberRoleManager), [Client#presenceUpdate](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate).

Comment: Its not worked. I didn't get any errors but bot not give roles.

Comment: I edited topic again can you look my lastest code? @darshan B